# svn post- and pre- commit hooks don't work when subversion gets commited

Tags: bash, scripts, svn

I have no idea how to fix it. I wrote a simple bash script which writes current date and time to the file, and put it to the post-commit and pre-commit hook. When I run this locally typing eg. ./pre-commit ./post-commit it works but when I commit to my svn, nothing happens. Maybe I missed something in configuration? Please, help me... Here's the script just to let you know what it is about:

```
filename="datefile"
echo "writing file ${filename}..."
echo "Commited..." > ${filename}
date | cut -d"," -f2 >> ${filename}
date | cut -d" " -f5 >> ${filename}
echo "Done!"
```

Thanks for any help.

ps. This is not a problem with perms, I already gave right ones to both, the scripts files and datefile.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you're missing the shebang line; the first line should read `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash`

Second, you're making assumptions on what the current working directory will be when the hook is run, so if it manages to run the script even though it's missing the important shebang line, it likely works, but writes `datefile` in a different directory than you assumed. Provide an absolute path to the file you want to write to.

Lastly, `${filename}` is bad practice, you should always quote variable expansions to avoid word splitting and pathname expansion: `"$filename"`. Also, instead of doing `date | cut ...`, just tell date to only output the bits you're after. E.g.

```
printf 'Commit happened at %s\n' "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")" > "$filename"
```

On a side note, bash's printf (since 4.0) can output date strings too.

```
printf 'Commit happened at %(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T\n' -1 > "$filename"
```

`man bash | less +/printf` to read more about printf.

Comment: Oh, I didn't really miss `#!/bin/bash` line, just forgot to copy it here, sorry...
I changed the path to the full one(looking at the server's files structure) and it still doesn't work :/ But... when I work on files which are on the server should I call 'em like through http/... or like a local path..? I also got rid of the {} in variables callings.